# How range works with for loop in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
for i in range(1,4,-1):
    print(i)
```

Here , "i" will be initialized as "1" which lies in [1, 4) , So it should print 1 , but it doesn't print anything. Why ?

Comment: There are multiple resources online. Try reading the docs for [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here your step value is negative

> For a positive step, the contents of a range r are determined by the formula r[i] = start + step*i where i >= 0 and r[i] < stop.
>
> For a negative step, the contents of the range are still determined by the formula r[i] = start + step*i, but the constraints are i >= 0 and r[i] > stop.

The first value would be `1 + (-1) * 0` = 1, which is less than your step value (4) and this fails the second constraint.

so if you go through the formula, its obvious nothing would get printed - [Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range)

Answer (score 1):

In order to make it work you should have: range(4, 1, -1).

As said on the documentation :

For a positive step, the contents of a range r are determined by the formula r[i] = start + step*i where i >= 0 and r[i] < stop.

For a negative step, the contents of the range are still determined by the formula r[i] = start + step*i, but the constraints are i >= 0 and r[i] > stop.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this part of the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#ranges):

> For a negative step, the contents of the range are still determined by
>   the formula r[i] = start + step*i, but the constraints are i >= 0 and
>   r[i] > stop.

Your first value would be `1 + (-1) * 0` = 1, which is less than your stop value of 4.
So the second constraint applies, and this value isn't kept. Your range is empty.